# Using stateful processing to identify and add missing timestamps in Apche Beam time series (Pcollection)

Tags: python, time-series, apache-beam, missing-data, stateful

I want to add missing timestamps in a pcollection. My idea is:

1. Use a state to create a list of all available time steps
2. Infer from the list which time steps are missing
3. Create a pcollection with all the time steps from step 2.
4. Make a union of both pcollections.

The problem I am having is with step 2, as I do not know how to grasp the list from the state. I tried this:

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.coders import StrUtf8Coder
from apache_beam.transforms.userstate import BagStateSpec


class StatefulBufferingFn(beam.DoFn):
  BUFFER_STATE = BagStateSpec('buffer', StrUtf8Coder())

  def process(self, element,
              buffer_state=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE)):

    buffer_state.add(element[1]['timestamp'])
    yield element

data = [
    ('2022-03-01 00:00:00', {'timestamp': '2022-03-01 00:00:00', 'value': 1}),
    ('2022-03-01 00:01:00', {'timestamp': '2022-03-01 00:01:00', 'value': 2}),
    ('2022-03-01 00:03:00', {'timestamp': '2022-03-01 00:03:00', 'value': 3}),
    ('2022-03-01 00:04:00', {'timestamp': '2022-03-01 00:04:00', 'value': 4})
]

def read_final_state(state_pcoll):
  def print_state(timestamps):
    print('Final state:', list(timestamps))
  return state_pcoll | beam.CombineGlobally(lambda x: x).without_defaults() | beam.Map(print_state)


with beam.Pipeline(runner='DirectRunner') as pipeline:
    result, final_state = (
            pipeline
            | 'Create data' >> beam.Create(data)
            | 'apply_beam' >> beam.ParDo(StatefulBufferingFn()).with_outputs('final_state', main='output'))

    read_final_state(final_state)
```

But the reading does not work. How would i get the entire list of all available time steps? btw, the missing time step in this example would be 2022-03-01 00:02:00.

Comment: Do you know the full list of possible dates when starting the pipeline?

Comment: Not necessarily, but suppose yes. What would you suppose?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the concept of the state wrong. According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-and-timers)

> Beam’s state API models **state per key**. [...] All state for a key is
> **scoped to** the **current window**. [...] State is always fully scoped only to the current processing key.

So each key (in your case timestamp) has its own `BagState`. If you would use additionaly windowing, the `BagState` would be reset for each window.

For your case, you will have 4 individual `BagStates` all of length 1 with the respective timestamp as content. Should you send another data point, e.g.

```
('2022-03-01 00:00:00', {'timestamp': '2022-03-01 00:00:00', 'value': 5})
```

the `BagState` belonging to `2022-03-01 00:00:00` would basically be `['2022-03-01 00:00:00', '2022-03-01 00:00:00']`. Furthermore, by design the state is only known inside your `StatefulBufferingFn`, there is no way to access it in other parts of your pipeline.

On the top of my head, I come up with the two following approaches (though I'm not happy with either of them and I don't know if they'll work)

Suppose you have the following data

```
data = [
    {'timestamp': '2022-03-01 00:00:00', 'value': 1},
    {'timestamp': '2022-03-01 00:01:00', 'value': 2},
    {'timestamp': '2022-03-01 00:03:00', 'value': 3},
    {'timestamp': '2022-03-01 00:04:00', 'value': 4}
]
```

1. Assuming you have a batch pipeline, you could go for a global `BagState` (by assigning all incoming data the same key) and using a [timer](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#timers) to periodically check for missing timestamps and impute them into your pipeline.

```
with beam.Pipeline(runner='DirectRunner') as pipeline:
    result, final_state = (
        pipeline
        | 'Create data' >> beam.Create(data)
        | 'Add dummy Key' >> beam.Map(lambda x: ('dummy', x))
        | beam.ParDo(BufferDoFn())
    )
```

and the BufferDoFn similar to the [Batching RPCs example](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#batching-rpcs)

```
class BufferDoFn(DoFn):
  BUFFER = BagStateSpec('buffer', EventCoder())
  IS_TIMER_SET = ReadModifyWriteStateSpec('is_timer_set', BooleanCoder())
  OUTPUT = TimerSpec('output', TimeDomain.REAL_TIME)

  def process(self,
              buffer=DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER),
              is_timer_set=DoFn.StateParam(IS_TIMER_SET),
              timer=DoFn.TimerParam(OUTPUT)):
    buffer.add(element)
    if not is_timer_set.read():
      timer.set(Timestamp.now() + Duration(seconds=10))  # adjust time
      is_timer_set.write(True)

  @on_timer(OUTPUT)
  def output_callback(self,
                      buffer=DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER),
                      is_timer_set=DoFn.StateParam(IS_TIMER_SET)):
    # instead of send_rpc do custom stuff
    outputs = check_missing_timestamps_and_impute(list(buffer.read()))
    for output in outputs:
        yield output
    # end of custom stuff
    buffer.clear()
    is_timer_set.clear()
```

where

```
def check_missing_timestamps_and_impute(seen_timestamps) -> list:
    # do comparison to expected dates (if known beforehand)
    # alternatively: extract dynamically which are missing (e.g., if they are equidistant, or you have 'gaps' in the BagState)
    # return list of imputed data (same structure as input data of your pipeline)
    pass
```

Possible drawbacks:
Pcollections in beam are not necessarily processed in order. It could be if you would have waited another second, the missing timestamp would have been added to the `BagState`. You will impute it, while in the next round it will be added to the buffer and generate a new 'gap' the next time the timer triggers. So you need to deal with duplicate/false imputes later.

2. If you know your set of timestamps before hand, you could initialize them as a separate input of your pipeline and use `CoGroupByKey` (see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/cogroupbykey/#examples)) to find the missing timestamps. The result will contain both your main input (e.g., `icons` in the linked example) and the separate input containing all expected timestamps (e.g., `durations` in the linked example). You need to check for cases where `icons` is empty and impute your missing data, and afterwards drop the 'joined' side input altogether.

I have not yet used `CoGroupByKey` myself. No idea how it will behave during streaming pipeline. You usually don't see all the data at the same time in beam. So it could well be that your `durations` are millions of datapoints, while your `icons` are only of size 10. The `CoGroupByKey`, however, will always return a PCollection of size `len(durations)`. Thus, you need to deal with multiple incorrectly imputed data afterwards (though, I guess you could check only for 'gaps' similar to above).

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. Option 2 is what i implemented, but i am not very satisfied. Option 1 seems very difficult, as even on a batch process there is no order and things might go wrong. I was just thinking of a third option: use fixed windows and then impute those values in a window if there is some missing. Does that make sense?

Comment: I haven't had much experience with windowing, so I can't answer that